# How to compile sass sourcemap in jekyll

Tags: sass, jekyll

I am using jekyll 3.4.0, 
i am using sass for styling my website. 
while compiling, it is won't create  style.css.map file in _site folder, which very helpful  for debugging.

My config.yml file

```
markdown: kramdown
port: 8080
sass:
  sass_dir: css
  sourcemap: true
  style: compact
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Jekyll (yet) supports SASS source maps.

For my projects I have added a SASS build step to my deploy script, which generates source map:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# destination folder in which the build result will be stored
DEST="./_site/style"

# folder in which original SCSS files will be places
ORIGINALS=$DEST/originals

# folder in which include SCSS file will be places
INCLUDES=$ORIGINALS/_sass

# remove the previous version of the folder
rm $ORIGINALS -r
mkdir $ORIGINALS

# copy original SASS include files to output folder
cp ./_sass/ $ORIGINALS -r

# name of the entry point SCSS file (without the extension)
SASS_FILE=style

# copying the entry point SCSS file to the output folder
# (removing the frontmatter from the file)
tail -n +3 ./style/$SASS_FILE.scss > $ORIGINALS/$SASS_FILE.scss

# building the entry SCSS file
sass --load-path $INCLUDES --sourcemap=auto $ORIGINALS/$SASS_FILE.scss $DEST/$SASS_FILE.css
```

### Important

Don't forget to configure your web server to server SCSS mime types.

### Additional notes

The important thing here is that original SCSS files **also get deployed** to the web server, so that a browser can access them!

Also `sourcemap` parameter needs to be set to `auto` so that correct relative paths to original SCSS files get inserted into sourcemap.